# Airflow logs in s3 bucket

Tags: airflow

Would like to write the airflow logs to s3. Following are the parameter that we need to set according to the doc-

```
remote_logging = True
remote_base_log_folder = 
remote_log_conn_id =
```

If Airflow is running in AWS, why do I have to pass the AWS keys? Shouldn't the boto3 API be able to write/read to s3 if correct permission are set on IAM role attached to the instance?

Answer (score 0):

Fair point, but I think it allows for more flexibility if Airflow is not running on AWS or if you want to use a specific set of credentials rather than give the entire instance access. It might have also been easier implementation as well because the underlying code for writing logs into S3 uses the S3Hook (https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.9/airflow/utils/log/s3_task_handler.py#L47), which requires a connection id.